# Simple Angular directive not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

here is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="storeController as store">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.product">
        <h3 product-name>
        </h3>
```

here is the product-name.html :

```
{{product.name}}
<em class="pull-right"> {{product.price | currency}}</em>
```

and here is my app.js :

```
//other code
app.directive("productName",function(){
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        templateUrl : "product-name.html"
    };
});
```

But when I refresh the HTML I don't see the information thats inside the product-name.html, what did I do wrong?

Comment: what is `app` ? I don't see that declared anywhere. I just see you trying to call .directive() on it.

Comment: app is my module var, I didn't paste all the app.js code because its long

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it should be `store.products` (plural)? Otherwise try to replicate it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/iZ9xjp5dIopc6sAjccKj?p=preview

Comment: oh no all other controllers work fine so the problem is with this specific directive, either implementation of it or initialization inside HTML is wrong.

Comment: What do you actually see? Did you try tasseKATT's plunker?